# How to switch audio output to specific devices per application using command line?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, configuration, devices, output

`pacmd list-clients` shows the applications, `pacmd list-sinks` shows the devices, the GUI tool `pavucontrol` can assign applications to the devices.

What is the command for assigning the devices?

For example, the script should be able to automatically do setups like that: grep for firefox among the clients, create a virtual input/output device, assign firefox to them, destroy the devices when done.

Comment: I don't know what you wnat to achieve with this, but here are some pointers from [a superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/182149/set-device-for-program-in-pulseaudio) that is similar to yours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pactl move-sink-input` [ID] [SINK]

Move the specified playback stream (identified by numerical index) to the specified sink (identified by symbolic name or numerical index).

[Ubuntu manpage: pactl](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/pactl.1.html)